# Running program.js from a different folder

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have node installed to

> C:\ProgramFile\nodejs

I started some tutorials a while ago and all of my js files are stored to the following path:

> C:\nodetut

Example:

> C:\nodetut\program.js

How do I run the program.js in the CMD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're already in the directory "C:\nodetut\" you should be able to run the app just by typing

```
node program.js
```

Or even

```
node program
```

Answer (score 3):

It should be like this:

```
C:\ProgramFile\nodejs C:\nodetut\program.js
```